# how to compare two time variables in jquery without date

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my jquery code.#StartTime and #EndTime is input form tag.starttime and entime contain time values only,not date value.then how to compare this two time values in jquery.
example:starttimeval=8:00 AM endtimeval=9:00 PM (not date value inside the variable only time)

```
   $(function() {
    $('#StartTime').datetimepicker({
        datepicker : false,
        format : 'g:i A'
    });
    $('#EndTime').datetimepicker({
        datepicker : false,
        format : 'g:i A'

    });
             var starttime=  $("#StartTime").val();
            var endtime= $("#EndTime").val();
  });
```

this is my form image.it's show time values.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the times are always on the hour, then here is a function that will convert the input value you have to 24 hour:

```
function getHour24(timeString)
{
    time = null;
    var matches = timeString.match(/^(\d{1,2}):00 (\w{2})/);
    if (matches != null && matches.length == 3)
    {
        time = parseInt(matches[1]);
        if (matches[2] == 'PM')
        {
            time += 12;
        }
    }
    return time;
}
```

Then if you want to find the difference, just do:

```
var starttime =  getHour24($("#StartTime").val());
var endtime = getHour24(($("#EndTime").val());

var timeDifference = endtime - starttime;
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Date object using constructor:

```
new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond);
```

And do simple comparison

```
var difference = dateObject1 - dateObject2;
```

Use 1 for year, day since there is no 0 year and day and use 0 for month since its indexed from 0.